# CodeIgniter "form_validation.php" not working as expected?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have got stummped on a problem where I can not see why codeIgniter is ignoring my rules setup in the "form_validation.php" in which i am using the following code.

```
$config = array(
'racedetails' => array(
    array(
        'field' => 'race_memberno',
        'label' => 'MembershipNumber',
        'rules' => 'required' 
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'race_penalties',
        'label' => 'Penalties',
        'rules' => 'required' 
    )
);
```

I am then calling the Validation set on my controller using:

```
$this->form_validation->run('racedetails');
```

However it always states false when ran, The form runs normal and returns no errors , Is there somthing else I may have missed ?

**The Above Validation run function runs within the following (Requested by Dale)**

```
public function index($id){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    if($this->form_validation->run('racedetails')){$validated++;} 

    if($validated != 1){
        $this->process_template_build('entries/entry',$data);
    }else {
      echo "Validation Passed";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code for the method that this lies within?

Comment: Did you try $this->form_validation->run($config['racedetails'])?

Comment: Yan - Yes did try with the $config put it just returns a undefined variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't you forget to actually use the `$config` file before running the validation?

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
```

Comment: Where should this be defined ? as this causes undifined variable "$config" when used in the controller constructor or function.

Comment: I had the impression this autoloaded the rules from the /application/config/form_validation.php 
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#savingtoconfig

Comment: It does if you have created a config file and placed in the application/config/. Judging by your response, you have ;-) How about enabling the logs? You can check if your config file gets loaded indeed.

Comment: Thanks Robert, It seemed like the "form_validation.php" config was not getting included so it was just a case of loading it into the config manualy and then setting the config as the rule as you stated before in your first post.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the reason was, that I´m using an own Form_validation class to stlye the error output globally.

There I forgot to pass the rules to the parent constructor. So this is how it works with an own MY_Form_Validation class:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

public function __construct($rules = array())
{
    parent::__construct($rules);

    $this->_error_prefix = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><span class="title"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> ERROR</span>';
    $this->_error_suffix = '</div>';

}

}
```